# Huffman Coding - Dealing with unicode

Tags: java, unicode, arrays, huffman-code

I've implemented a Huffman coding in java, that works on byte data from an input file. However, it only works when compressing ascii. I'd like to extend it so that it can deal with characters that are larger than 1 byte long, but I'm not sure how to do this exactly.

```
private static final int CHARS = 256;     
private int [] getByteFrequency(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte [] bb = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        int [] aa = new int[CHARS];
            if(fis.read(bb) == bb.length) {
                System.out.print("Uncompressed data: ");
                for(int i = 0; i < bb.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print((char) bb[i]);
                        aa[bb[i]]++;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        return aa;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { throw new FileNotFoundException(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
}
```

For example, this is what I'm using to get the frequency of the characters in the file, and obviously it only works on a single byte. If I give it a unicode file, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at `aa[bb[i]]++;`, and i is normally a negative number. I know this is because `aa[bb[i]]++;` is only looking at one byte, and the unicode character will be more than one, but I'm not sure on how I can change it.

Can anybody give me some pointers?

Comment: Why treat it as unicode instead of a byte array?

Comment: @JeffFerland: If you look at his code - he IS using it as a byte array, he just falls into the "signed byte" pit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
private static final int CHARS = 256;     
private int [] getByteFrequency(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte [] bb = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        int [] aa = new int[CHARS];
            if(fis.read(bb) == bb.length) {
                System.out.print("Uncompressed data: ");
                for(int i = 0; i < bb.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print((char) bb[i]);
                        aa[((int)bb[i])&0xff]++;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        return aa;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { throw new FileNotFoundException(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
}
```

If i'm correct (I haven't tested it), your problem is that byte is a SIGNED value in java. The cast to integer + masking it to 0xff should handle it correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I no longer get the negative value problem after adding this. However, there seems to be a problem with the characters being read in. This probably comes down to my lack of knowledge of character encoding, but when I give it a file containing 'āčôęłüÿß', it interprets it as 'ￄﾁￄﾍￃﾴￄﾙￅﾂￃﾼￃ﾿ￃﾟ'. Then after that when I do the mapping of characters to codes, it's getting a bunch of other symbols (e.g. ¼, ¿, etc..). None of which were in the input file.

Comment: @Kumalh Well, you're handling the file as a byte array, so the encoding should be irrelevant. Maybe at other places you need to do the same casting to handle the byte values correctly?

BTW, you could optimize the code to NOT read the complete file into memory, but only handle chunks to build the frequency map.

Comment: Could it be that some characters require more than one byte? And my program is only reading in a single byte at a time, thus misinterpreting it?
As for the optimisation, I might consider that at a later stage, as right now I'm more concerned with just getting it working! Thanks for the thought though, I'll look into that.

Comment: @Kumalh: Now i understand what you mean. You don't read characters, you read the bytes, the characters are composed of. in UTF-8 or UTF-16 the/some characters will need more than one byte, and though you see "incomplete fragments" when debuuging.

As long as you compress those bytes (regardless of what they mean) and later on decompress them to the exactly same bytes, the content will not change, and with the correct encoding you'll see your umlauts and co again.

Comment: Sorry! I should have been more clear. It's been a long night..
So when I'm compressing multiple bytes, is there some way of knowing whether UTF-8 or UTF-16 has been used, or just plain single byte characters? I'd like it to be possible for any character encoding to be used in an input file.
Edit: And once I know the encoding, how can I predict how many bytes a character will take up, given that it's not a consistent number?

Comment: If you encode ALL bytes, you don't need to care about whether your content represent text in any obsucre (may it be UTF-8, UTF-7, UTF-16 or even some other) encoding or image data or whatever. If you Put the bytes back in the same order, your compression/decompression will work.   If you want to handle the input in a aprotiate encoding you'll need to know the encoding , i would advise to use the Reader/Writer classes then, using the correct encoding.